# Are JavaScript Asynchronous Functions Always Passed into the Message Queue?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to understand JavaScript asynchronous functions and the event loop better.

Are callbacks passed into asynchronous functions always handled by the web API (or Node.js API for example) then passed into a message queue, then eventually passed into the call stack?

Is this different than synchronous functions which are never passed into the message queue and go directly to the call stack?

Here's an image for a reference to what I'm referring to:
[image]

Comment: Yes, your description is correct. [Here's a great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) that shows/describes it.

Comment: Thxs Scott Marcus!